# Масштабирование Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet

Может немного глупый вопрос, но все же задам.
Допустим, есть стандартная конфигурация Spring MVC приложения (как из примеров в интернете) с одним  DispatcherServlet:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>My application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

За ним есть один @Controller, и один @Service , в котором производится некая работа, которая занимает, допустим, 2 секунды. Как будет вести себя приложение, если одновременно к нему придет 10 одинаковых запросов? Все запросы будут обрабатываться последовательно? Или для каждого запроса будет создан отдельный экземпляр DispatcherServlet и контекст бинов?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web-контейнер имеет пул потоков для обработки запросов. На каждый запрос из пула берётся поток и в нём запускается метод контроллера. По умолчанию все последующие вызовы из этого метода будут выполняться в том же потоке. Если запросов поступает больше, чем есть потоков в пуле, запросы встают в очередь и ждут освобождения одного из потоков. Для пользователя это выглядит как медленно отвечающий сайт. Если очередь переполняется, клиенты начинают получать ошибку 502. Поэтому тяжёлые задачи стоит запускать в отдельном пуле потоков или вовсе переложить на фоновый процесс. Первое в Spring очень легко делается - достаточно пометить тяжёлый метод аннотацияей [@Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html). А DispatcherServlet и контекст создаётся единожды - при запуске web-приложения, обычно в момент запуска сервера.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что раз создается один экземпляр DispatcherServlet  и один контекст (где все бины - синглтоны) - то все потоки будут обращаться к одному экземпляру сервлета, контроллера и сервисов? То есть, все запросы выполняются параллельно в разных потоках с общими разделяемыми ресурсами? И если синхронизировать метод на любом этапе цепи обработки  - запросы, в итоге, будут упираться в монитор и обрабатываться последовательно?

Comment: Да, всё так и есть.